# Inexplicable "':' expected" error from setStyle in AS2

Tags: css, flash, actionscript-2, stylesheet

Why the heck does line three claim that a ':' is expected?  Note that that is a colon - not a semicolon.

```
import TextField.StyleSheet;
var s:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
s.setStyle("ss", {baseline-shift: -35, font-size: 10});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing

```
s.setStyle("ss", {baseline-shift: -35, font-size: 10});
```

to

```
s.setStyle("ss", {"baseline-shift": -35, "font-size": 10});
```

should work. Notice the quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like problem is caused by "-" sign.
Maybe you should take a look here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/help.html?content=00001563.html

Not sure what about "baseline-shift" in AS2, but instead "font-size" you should try "fontSize".